# I'm travel from Kenya to Amsterdam to Athens is that need a transit visa? Or any kind of visa I'm a permanent resident of Greece

Tags: visas

I want to travel from Kenya to Amsterdam and to Athens. Does that need a transit or any other kind of visa? I'm a permanent resident of Greece and I travel with my Kenyan passport.